# How to add elements on a std::vector only if their type matches

Tags: c++, vector

I have a base class `fruit` and subclasses `oranges` and `apples`. Both subclasses overload `operator+` so that I know how to sum oranges or apples. Now I have a vector of references to the base class `std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<fruit>>` and I would like to know how many apples and oranges are stored in that vector, how do I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <algorithm>

struct fruit { virtual ~fruit() = default; };

struct apple : fruit {};
struct orange : fruit {};


auto count_oranges(std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<fruit>> const& vec) -> std::size_t
{
    return std::count_if(begin(vec), end(vec), [](auto&& ref)
    {
        return typeid(ref.get()) == typeid(orange);
    });
}
```

Comment: or `dynamic_cast` depending how OP wants to handle sub-classes of `orange`.